# Sharing initialisation of a roles attribute between the attribute and methods

Tags: c#, arrays, attributes

I have a permissions attribute which takes a list of enum values for roles:

```
    [CheckRoles(SystemRole.ID.Admin, SystemRole.ID.User)]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
            ....
    }
```

However, in other parts of the code I would like to check if the user is in any of these roles, so I can go to the correct page.  So the code looks something like:

```
if (roles.IsInAnyRoles(user, SystemRole.ID.Admin, SystemRole.ID.User)
{
    ... Do something in MyController ...
}
```

You can see the repetition here.  I really want to have the two roles in a variable or initialiser list or something, that I can pass to both the Attribute and the method.  Creating a const array doesn't work.  Is there a way of doing this?  Can I store the array initialiser somehow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE

I have made the roles enum int a Flags enum (and given the items appropriate values).  This means I can or the values together to give a single, constant value.
I can now use that constant value in the Attribute, and in methods.
Thanks to Danny Chen below.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `CheckRolesAttribute` ?

Comment: CheckRolesAttribute has the following constructors:
public CheckRolesAttribute();
public CheckRolesAttribute(params SystemRole.ID[] roles);
SystemRole.ID is an enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my real project experiences, I'd like to define roles like this;

```
[Flags]
public enum Role
{
   Staff = 0,
   Supervisor = 1,
   Manager = 2,
   Admin = 4,
   HelpDesk = 8 
}
```

The reason is that one account often has a few roles associated, e.g. someone is a supervisor of Bob, also he is the manager of IT department. In this case his role is `Role.Supervisor | Role.Manager`, so that he could use all functions provided to Role.Supervisor (such as approving Bob's leaving request), meanwhile he can approve leaving requests from all IT department staff. The action looks like:

```
[CheckRole(Role.Supervisor, Role.Manager)]
public ActionResult ApproveLeavingRequest()
{
    //the roles in the constructor of CheckRoleAttribute are OR related
}

[CheckRole(Role.Manager|Role.Supervisor, Role.Admin)]
public ActionRequest ModifySystemSettings()
{
    //this method is provided to a small group of people
    //those who is a manager and a supervisor
    //or he is an admin
}

[CheckRole(Role.Manager|Role.Supervisor|Role.Admin)] 
           //maybe we need to add Role.Boss into the system :)
public ActionRequest IncreasePay()
{
    //only the boss account can invoke this method
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I have gone through and implemented it.  However, while it fixes my problem, it doesn't answer the original question... So I changed the question!